# The probability of a coin entirely inside a given square

Tags: probability

There is a square whose each edge has length 4. And there is a coin with the radius 1. If the coin is assumed to touch the square. Then what is the probability of the coin being inside the square entirely? I think I just have to trace the center of the coin and the answer is $1/9$ Is it correct?

Comment: What does the sentence "If the coin is assumed to touch the square." mean?

Comment: Oh it just means that the coin must always be in contact with the square.

Comment: Then the probability is $0$.

Comment: I think all you mean to say is that the center of the coin is uniformly distributed in the interior of the square.  If so, then the center must lie inside the square of sidelength $3$ with the same center (and parallel to  the sides).  That smaller square has area $9$ and the big one has area $16$ so...  But if you mean something else then of course the answer will be different.

Comment: Correction:  The smaller square should have sidelength $2$, not $3$ as I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The grey zone represents the set of the possible locations for the center of the coin, if the coin is not completely outside the square. Its area is $32+\pi$. The green zone is a subset of the grey zone and it represents the set of the possible locations for the center of the coin, if the coin is entirely inside the square. Its area is $4$. Hence by interpreting the word *probability (distribution)* in the most (?) reasonable way we have that the answer is 
$$ \frac{4}{32+\pi}\approx 11.38\% > \frac{1}{9}.$$